# Ember testing Oauth routes with Qunit

Tags: ember.js, qunit, acceptance

I've no experience in testing and I was wondering how to test unauthorized route requests on ember qunit

Currently what i've done is this. Goes to a route ( gets sent off ) Looks for div that exists on the authorised route and if the div doesnt exist the Test passes.

```
visit("/specimen/specimenadd").then(function() {
        ok(!exists(".specimenAdd"), "Specimen Add Route is not accessible - OK");
 });
```

Also How to visit given route:

```
this.route('specimenview', { path: "view-specimen/:specimen_id"});
```

Edit - Found out how to visit such route

```
visit("/specimen/view-specimen/1").then(function() {
            ok(!exists(".specimenMain"), "Specimen View/1 is not accessible - OK");
        });
```

Cant use given example cause the "specimenList route is unforbidden"

```
visit("/posts").then(function() {
    return click("td a:first");
  }).then(function() { // Have first item open });
```